# My Recyclerview sometimes display data and sometimes it doesnt

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My Recyclerview sometimes needs a refresh to start displaying data, some times it need much time to display the data and sometimes it works like a charm. I even used the same adapter for 2 recycler views one of them displayed data immediately but the other didn't show at all like the the image below:

[image]

This problem started to show up when I added another recycler view but in a different fragment that used same adapter. I thought using same adapter was the problem so I created a new one but the problem is still there. Note: I'm using same layout for displaying the recycler view items too. Any Ideas would be really helpful.
Thanks

UPDATE: Codes

Adapter :

```
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.TextureView
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.ecommapp.R
import com.example.ecommapp.main_activity.data.Product
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.product_item_layout.view.*

class ProductItemAdapter(val listener: ProductItemAdapter.onItemClickListener) : ListAdapter<Product, ProductItemAdapter.ProductViewHolder>(Comparator()) {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_item_layout, parent, false)
        return ProductViewHolder(inflater)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        if (currentItem != null) {
            holder.bind(currentItem)
        }
    }

    inner class ProductViewHolder(view : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        init {
            view.setOnClickListener{
                val position = adapterPosition
                val product = getItem(position)
                if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    listener.onItemClick(product)
                }
            }

        }

        private val container = view.container_main

        private val imageView = view.img_product_item_not_card
        private val productName = view.tv_product_item_label
        private val productNewPrice = view.tv_product_item_new_price
        private val productOldPrice = view.tv_product_item_old_price

        fun bind(product: Product) {

            productName.text = product.title
            productNewPrice.text = product.price

            /*var temp = (product.price as Double ) * 1.5
            var oldPrice = temp as String

            productOldPrice.text = oldPrice
            productOldPrice.paintFlags = productOldPrice.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG*/


            //Context of the view
            Glide.with(imageView.context) // Context
                .load(product.image) // Data
                .into(imageView) // View

        }

    }

    interface onItemClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(product : Product)
    }

    class Comparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Product>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Product, newItem: Product) =
            oldItem.id == newItem.id

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Product, newItem: Product) =
            oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.*
import com.example.ecommapp.main_activity.data.Product
import com.example.ecommapp.main_activity.retrofit.ProductsApi
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import dagger.hilt.android.scopes.ViewModelScoped
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import javax.inject.Inject




@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    val api : ProductsApi
) : ViewModel() {

    var new_collection_list : MutableLiveData<List<Product>>
    var best_sellling_list : MutableLiveData<List<Product>>

    init {
        new_collection_list = MutableLiveData()
        best_sellling_list = MutableLiveData()

        get_best_selling_data()
        get_new_collection_data()
    }

     fun get_new_collection_data(){

        var call = api.get_products_desc()
         call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Product>> {
             override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Product>>, response: Response<List<Product>>) {
                 if (response.body() != null){
                     new_collection_list.postValue(response.body())
                     Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Success Response")
                 }

                 else{
                     new_collection_list.postValue(null)
                     Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Null Response")
                }
             }

             override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Product>>, t: Throwable) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Failure Response")
             }
         })
    }
     fun get_best_selling_data() {

         var call = api.get_products_asc()
         call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Product>> {
             override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Product>>, response: Response<List<Product>>) {

                 if (response.body() != null){
                     best_sellling_list.postValue(response.body())
                     Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Success Response")
                 }
                 else{
                     best_sellling_list.postValue(null)
                     Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Null Response")
                 }
             }

             override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Product>>, t: Throwable) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Failure Response")
             }
         })
    }


    fun on_swipe_refresh(){
        get_new_collection_data()
        get_best_selling_data()
    }
}
```

Fragment :

```
package com.example.ecommapp.main_activity.fragments.home_fragment

import android.content.Context
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
import com.example.ecommapp.R
import com.example.ecommapp.main_activity.data.Product
import com.example.ecommapp.main_activity.shared_files.recycler_view_adapters.ProductItemAdapter
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.home_fragment_layout.*


@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment: Fragment(R.layout.home_fragment_layout), ProductItemAdapter.onItemClickListener {


    lateinit var new_collection_list : LiveData<List<Product>>
    lateinit var best_selling_list : LiveData<List<Product>>

    val new_collections_adapter = ProductItemAdapter(this)
    val best_selling_adapter = ProductItemAdapter(this)

    val viewModel : HomeViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        // New Collection Recycler View Setup
        rv_new_collections.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
            activity?.applicationContext,
            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
            false
        )


        rv_new_collections.adapter = new_collections_adapter


        // Best Selling Recycler View Setup
        rv_best_selling.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
            activity?.applicationContext,
            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
            false
        )


        rv_best_selling.adapter = best_selling_adapter

        //
        set_data()


        Handler().postDelayed({

            if ( isConnected(activity?.applicationContext) ){

                layout_new_collection_shimmer.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                rv_new_collections.visibility = View.VISIBLE


                layout_best_selling_shimmer.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                rv_best_selling.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                set_data()
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext, "No Internet Connection, Swipe to reload.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG )
                    .show()
            }


        }, 2000)


        container_swipe.setOnRefreshListener(object : SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
            override fun onRefresh() {

                if ( isConnected(activity?.applicationContext) ){

                    if( layout_new_collection_shimmer.visibility == View.INVISIBLE){

                        layout_new_collection_shimmer.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                        rv_new_collections.visibility = View.VISIBLE


                        layout_best_selling_shimmer.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                        rv_best_selling.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }


                    viewModel.on_swipe_refresh()
                    set_data()
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext, "No Internet Connection, Swipe to reload.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG )
                        .show()
                }



                // Must be added
                container_swipe.isRefreshing = false
            }


        })


    }

    fun set_data(){
        new_collection_list = viewModel.new_collection_list
        best_selling_list = viewModel.best_sellling_list

        new_collection_list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

            new_collections_adapter.submitList(it)
            new_collections_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })

        best_selling_list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            best_selling_adapter.submitList(it)
            best_selling_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }

    fun isConnected(ctx: Context?): Boolean {

        val hasInternet: Boolean

        val connectivityManager =
            ctx?.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
            val actNw =
                connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(networkCapabilities) ?: return false
            hasInternet = when {
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                actNw.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                else -> false
            }
        } else {
            hasInternet = try {
                if (connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo == null) {
                    false
                } else {
                    connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo?.isConnected!!
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                false
            }
        }
        return hasInternet}

    override fun onItemClick(product : Product) {
        val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToProductFragment(product, product.title, R.id.homeFragment)
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }


}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_swipe"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".main_activity.fragments.home_fragment.HomeFragment"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"

                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"

                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:outlineProvider="bounds"

                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/img_advertisment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/search_view"

                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
                android:background="#00000000"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/advertisment"
                    />

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_new_collection"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img_advertisment"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_new_collection"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Collections"
                    android:textColor="@color/tomato"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Show All"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#c6c4ce"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_new_collection_shimmer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:shimmer_repeat_mode="restart"
                    app:shimmer_shape="linear"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv_new_collection"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        >
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <include layout="@layout/product_shimmer_layout"></include>

                            <include layout="@layout/product_shimmer_layout"></include>

                            <include layout="@layout/product_shimmer_layout"></include>

                            <include layout="@layout/product_shimmer_layout"></include>

                            <include layout="@layout/product_shimmer_layout"></include>

                            <include layout="@layout/product_shimmer_layout"></include>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </HorizontalScrollView>
                </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/rv_new_collections"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="350dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv_new_collection"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/product_item_layout"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_best_selling"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/container_new_collection"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_best_selling"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Best Selling"
                    android:textColor="@color/tomato"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Show All"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#c6c4ce"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    />

                <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_best_selling_shimmer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:shimmer_repeat_mode="restart"
                    app:shimmer_shape="linear"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv_best_selling">

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <include layout="@layout/product_shimmer_layout"></include>

                            <include layout="@layout/product_shimmer_layout"></include>

                            <include layout="@layout/product_shimmer_layout"></include>

                            <include layout="@layout/product_shimmer_layout"></include>

                            <include layout="@layout/product_shimmer_layout"></include>

                            <include layout="@layout/product_shimmer_layout"></include>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </HorizontalScrollView>

                </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_best_selling"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="350dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tv_best_selling"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/product_item_layout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>






</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: can you share some code snippet to check and analyze further to to find the issue

Comment: the snippet is for both recylerview using same adapter right ?

Comment: Yes they are both the same only different lists @dinkar_kumar

Comment: and you sure both of the API getting executed successfully and data been properly fetched from both API ?

Comment: Yes. If not the second recycler view would never show data like in this image

Comment: I mean the second API is also giving the response for which the view is not rendered ?

Comment: Yes, and it's recycler view has the same behavior. Sometimes it loads data fast and some sometimes it doesn't load at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231858/discussion-between-mumen-ahmed-and-dinkar-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

I Figured out what is the problem. The API takes much time to send the data. So, the recycler view renders the view with null values.

Comment: no buddy that is not the problem, you can update the recyler view with data whenever you received from API by passing it to adapter and calling notifydatasetchanged and it will update the recyclerview

Comment: I made sure of that. You can try adding 

Handler().postDelayed({
            set_data() // Function to observe data from the view model
        },3000) 
and you will see that it works fine. @dinkar_kumar

Comment: that is a very bad design anyway and that is not needed in the 1st place.
moreover your design is also on the assumptions that your API will be able to get executed successfully in 3 seconds even in high latency and low bandwidth network.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you. But it's been hours on this trying to figure out what is the problem but couldn't. So I don't know what to do but this

Comment: Can you confirm Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Success Response") is been called for your `get_new_collection_data` ?

Comment: Yes I confirmed that all the Success Logs are called.

Comment: can you try to replace `it` with `viewModel.new_collection_list` and `viewModel.best_sellling_list` as per correct observe in your fragment